# ASUS E45M1-I DELUXE temperature limits

Tags: motherboard, temperature, lm-sensors

I have two questions about the temperature with [ASUS E45M1-I DELUXE](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_CPU_on_Board/E45M1I_DELUXE/). The chassis is [Chenbro ES34069](http://www.chenbro.eu/corporatesite/products_detail.php?sku=78).

1. What is the upper temperature limit of this board? Nothing related in manual nor homepage.
2. How do I setup the limits with `lm-sensors` under debian?

My current `/etc/sensors3.conf` is related to the following:

```
chip "k10temp-*"

    label temp1 "M/B Temp"

    set temp1_min 0
    set temp1_max 70
    set temp1_crit 85
```

but this don't work, `sensors` will output this:

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
M/B Temp: +81.8°C (high = +70.0°C)
                  (crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +97.0°C)
```

The label is correct but the limits aren't used.

**Edit:** Thanks to @ZaB I know that it is NOT the M/B Temp, it's the CPU Temp. But how do I setup the limits with `sensors3.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k10temp shows CPU temperature. depending on semiconductor and cooling technology maximum is between 50 and 150C (read the CPU spec sheet)

Comment: Now I know that k10temp is the CPU temperature, thanks! The mainboard is shipped with the AMD E450 processor which is not buyable from "normal" customers so it have no public datasheet. But I ask the mainboard manufacturer Asus to tell me what the limits are.

Comment: temperature limits are read from BIOS: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/k10temp
PS I also failed to find a specification of processor with thermal range

Comment: Thanks for the k10 link, @ZaB. I got a response vom Asus which set the max limit to 75°C and crit to 80°C. So how to override the limits with `sensors3.conf`?

Comment: Particular hybrid GPU/CPU processor has a thermal control circuitry and frequency scaling inside. There is very little motherboard can do about it. sensors3.conf are calibration quirks for thermal monitoring chips found on older motherboards. 

    acpitz-virtual-0
    Adapter: Virtual device
    temp1:        +66.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
    temp2:        +69.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)
    
    k8temp-pci-00c3
    Adapter: PCI adapter
    Core0 Temp:   +66.0°C  
    Core1 Temp:   +66.0°C  

You can run sensors-detect - maybe Radeon part of your CPU has another thermometer.